# Office 365 store restrictions and SharePoint online add-in permissions for creating sites

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I submitted an office 365 SharePoint add-in app for certification in the Office Store, and was told that one of the changes required is that I remove the 'Full Control' permission for the app, as it is not supported in the store. My app enables the user to create a new web site based on certain criteria. The add-in works correctly with 'Full Control' permission, but does not work with lower levels such as 'Manage'.

If the store does not allow me to use 'Full Control', what permissions or options can I use in order to still be able to create sites on behalf of the user?

Is there a different way to go about having the add-in app create sites in an existing site collection? The trigger can be user initiated, or event based.

I would love to get any ideas or solutions for this - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is to create a web service that is external to SharePoint and create the site in the service.

Here are a couple of resources that may help you:

[Walkthrough: Building a Custom Web API for use with SharePoint Online](http://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2017/03/12/walkthrough-building-a-custom-web-api-for-use-with-sharepoint-online/)

[PnP Webcast - Calling external APIs securely from SharePoint Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDjKRfHA1nw)